# Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer MDP Initialization

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

What is the best way to perform initialization on DefaultMessageListenerContainer initialization? Currently I am waiting for first message, and keep track of it using a boolean variable, which isn't so pretty. Is there a better way ? I want to read and load certain data into the cache once the Message Driven POJO is started up, so the message processing is faster.

(Edited)

**Spring Config Fragement:**

```
<bean id="itemListener" class="com.test.ItemMDPImpl" autowire="byName" />

<bean id="itemListenerAdapter" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <property name="delegate" ref="itemListener" />
    <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="processItems" />
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="itemMessageConverter" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="itemMqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="${item_queue_name}" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="itemListenerAdapter" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="3000" />
</bean>
```

I would like to have some initialization done before any message is received by the listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use `@PostConstruct` to annotate a method on `ItemMDPImpl` to perform startup initialization, just like any other Spring bean?

[4.9.6 @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations)